# IF Condition (js)

Tags: javascript

```js
var initialBalance = prompt("Initial balance:");
initialBalance = parseInt(initialBalance);
var choice = prompt("Deposit, Withdraw, Balance");
choice = choice.toUpperCase();

if (choice = D) {
  var deposit = prompt("Deposit amount:");
  alert(deposit + initialBalance);
}
```

My code allows for the user to input information but it doesn't seem to register what has been inputted because it straight up ignores the if condition and goes to a blank page. Not sure how to get my if statements to work.

Comment: `if (choice === 'D')`

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Assignment operator `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2) You should use [Abstract equality `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) or [Strict Equality `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity). And `D` should be inside `""` because its not variable.
And also convert input from user to number using `+`

```
if (choice === 'D') {
   var deposit = +prompt("Deposit amount:");
   alert(deposit + initialBalance);
}
```

#### Simplified Code:

```js
var initialBalance = +prompt("Initial balance:");
var choice = prompt("Deposit, Withdraw, Balance").toUpperCase();
if (choice === 'D') alert(+prompt("Deposit amount:") + initialBalance);
```

Comment: Can I know the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have no variable named `D` - you want to check against the *string* `"D"`. Also use the `==` (comparison) operator rather than the `=` (assignment) operator:

```
if (choice == "D") {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the inputs to `Number` from string, In the if condition make the `D` a string and also use `==` for comparison

```
if (choice=='D')
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Assignment 6</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
var initialBalance = prompt("Initial balance:");
initialBalance = parseInt(initialBalance);
var choice = prompt("Deposit, Withdraw, Balance");
choice = choice.toUpperCase();

if (choice=='D') {
var deposit = prompt("Deposit amount:");
alert(+deposit + 
+initialBalance);
}
  </script> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an assignment operator `=` You should use `==` (abstract equality) or `===` (strict equality). Ensure that you understand the difference between each before using. Also, it doesn't appear that variable D is located in your code.